# Iam getting-TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

Iam creating a bot with Microsoft bot framework which has to be integrated with MS Teams.Iam getting the following error-TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null on compiling the code,when i extend TeamsActivityHandler class to overwrite the onmessage method.

The code works fine with ActivityHandler class though.

The code below throws an error

```
const { TeamsActivityHandler} = require('botbuilder');

class mybot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    bunch of other codes here.
}
```

where as this below one works fine

```
const { ActivityHandler} = require('botbuilder');

class mybot extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    bunch of other codes here.
}
```

Comment: I don't use Node very much, so this is just a suggestion, but "TeamsActivityHandler" is quite new, so check what version of "botbuilder" you're using

Comment: i upgraded the botbuilder version with botbuilder-teams package,still the issue persists.

Comment: please provide the error that was thrown

Comment: Hi Mox , Error thrown -TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Comment: @SreeNath, I believe that is because there is no such object called `TeamsActivityHandler` that was being exported. you may wanna check your `botbuilder` code in `node_modules`

Comment: Alternatively, try without { }

Comment: @SreeNath, I assume the botbuilder version you have updated is  "~4.6.0" in your package.json file. This sample for [Teams Conversation Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot) will help you to tackle the issue. Let me know if you need any assistance on it.

Answer (score 0):

Hilton is correct, TeamsActivityHandler is new-ish (4.6.0+ like Trinetra said), I would look at your packages.

Along with the smaller dependencies, and various packages, a bot that uses TeamsActivityHanlder needs the following:

> botbuilder
>
> botbuilder-core
>
> botframework-connector
>
> botframework-schema

Most of these are installed as dependencies, so if you `npm install botbuilder`, you'll catch the rest.

You'll note 'Botbuilder-teams' is NOT on that list. Botbuilder-teams is deprecated [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-teams) I saw from your comment that you said you'd updated that package. If you're following a tutorial or example that uses it, you're using an outdated resource. Please look into the Teams-based samples on  the Botframework repo that Trinetra-MSFT referenced.

[image: teams packages]

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, please select is as the correct answer, so that future community members might benefit from it. Thank you!